# Is the Next.js cache and the Vercel cache the same thing?

Tags: caching, next.js, vercel

I have been reading up on [caching in Next.js](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/fundamentals)  and Vercel lately, but struggle to understand the differences between various caches and how they work under the hood.

**What We Know About Next.js 13 Caching**

- [Next.js Cache is a persistent HTTP cache that can be globally distributed](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/fundamentals#caching-data)
- Next.js 13 allows the developer to [control caching on both the component -and the fetch() request level](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/caching)
- It is possible to revalidate (i.e. update) the Next.js cache with fresh data, [either on-demand](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/revalidating#on-demand-revalidation) or [on a pre-set time interval](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/revalidating#background-revalidation)
- There is a folder in the next build output called `.next/cache`

**What We Know About Vercel Caching**

- [Vercel Edge Network cache caches content at the edge](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/edge-network/caching)
- [Static files are automatically cached at the edge after the first request](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/edge-network/caching#static-files-caching)
- [Vercel won't allow bypassing the cache for static files](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/edge-network/caching#cacheable-responses)
- [Response header `X-Vercel-Cache`](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/edge-network/caching#x-vercel-cache) contains details about state of cache for the requested resource
- [There is also a so-called "Build cache"](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/deployments/troubleshoot-a-build#understanding-build-cache), which stores `.next/cache`, `node_modules`, `package-lock.json`
- On each build, the Build cache is *only* updated with content from these folders if the content has changed
- [It is possible to delete existing *Build cache*](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/deployments/troubleshoot-a-build#managing-build-cache)

**What I Do Not Understand**

1. Where is the Next.js cache stored?
2. Where is the Vercel cache stored?
3. What is the `.next/cache` folder used for ([vague info here](https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment#nextjs-build-api))?
4. Are the Next.js and the Vercel caches the same? In other words, is Vercel just providing the actual storage for the resources saved in `.next/cache`?
5. If data fetched with `fetch()` is cached (as Next.js describes), how does that differ / relate to caching of entire HTML / JS / CSS bundles (which are created build-time or dynamically upon request)?

---

**Referred Resources**

1. https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/fundamentals
2. https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/caching
3. https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/revalidating
4. https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/edge-network/caching
5. https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/deployments/troubleshoot-a-build
6. https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment

Comment: Did you find the answer for queries?

Comment: @AakashGoplani No, unfortunately not.